# How can I fix this very basic Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a very basic chrome extension that changes a label on the screen to "hi", but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1",
  "description": "Testing",
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["http://roblox.com/*"],
          "js": ["jquery.min.js"]
      }
  ],

  "background": {
      "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "run.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "<all_urls>",
      "contentSettings"
  ]
}
```

and this is the background script that is supposed to change the label

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: "$('.robux-amount').text('hi')"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't find an obvious fault. Could it be that the label is dynamically added after the page finishes loading (after `complete` fires)

Comment: I don't think so.  I added a loop to the code, and the label still isn't changing.

Comment: Any errors in the page's console? Does it work if you simply run it there?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed it's saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: I suppose you can fix it then by adding `"run_at": "document_start"` in the manifest to the content script. Try it, I'll post it as an answer if it works.

Comment: I'm still getting the error after adding that to the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your jquery.min.js is not getting included at the time of tabs update (on which you have attached a listener)
Try this

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "jquery.min.js" }, function () {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: "$('.robux-amount').text('hi')"
        });
    }
    });
});
```